# create index variable based on values from different rows in R

Tags: r, variables

For my research, I would like to do analyses in parent/child dyads. I have an ID number, a family number and the status of the participant (1 and 2 are children, 3 is a parent). I would like to have all families containing at least one child and one parent ("dyad"). So within each family_ID, at least status 1 or 2 and 3 must be present, such as family 10001, 10002 and 10004 in the example below. Families containing only children or parents (e.g. family 10003 in the example below must be removed).

```
ID_no    family_ID   status
1        10001       1
2        10001       3
3        10002       1
4        10002       2
5        10002       3
6        10003       1
7        10003       1
8        10004       2
9        10004       3
10       10004       3
```

I would like to have a data frame with the family_ID and dyad (1=yes, 0=no)

```
family_ID   dyad
10001       1
10002       1
10003       0
10004       1
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's a version using dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
dyads.df <- family.df%>%
    group_by(family_ID)%>%
    mutate(gotParent=3%in%status,gotChild=1%in%status|2%in%status,retain=gotParent&gotChild)%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    filter(retain==TRUE)%>%
    select(1:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"ID_no    family_ID   status
1        10001       1
2        10001       3
3        10002       1
4        10002       2
5        10002       3
6        10003       1
7        10003       1
8        10004       2
9        10004       3
10       10004       3")
with(df1, tapply(status %in% 3, family_ID, FUN=any) & 
       (tapply(status %in% 1, family_ID, FUN=any) | tapply(status %in% 2, family_ID, FUN=any) )
)
# 10001 10002 10003 10004 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

variant:

```
with(df1, tapply(status==3, family_ID, FUN=any) & 
       (tapply(status==1, family_ID, FUN=any) | tapply(status==2, family_ID, FUN=any) )
)
```

another variant:

```
tapply(df1$status, df1$family_ID, FUN=function(x) any(x==3) && (any(x==1)||any(x==2)))
```

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df1)[, .(dyad=any(status==3) && (any(status==1) || any(status==2))), family_ID]
# > setDT(df1)[, .(dyad=any(status==3) && (any(status==1) || any(status==2))), family_ID]
#    family_ID  dyad
# 1:     10001  TRUE
# 2:     10002  TRUE
# 3:     10003 FALSE
# 4:     10004  TRUE
```